# GPS doesn't update

Tags: android, gps

Good evening everyone,

I'm currently doing an application which get the values of different sensors like the accelerometer, the proximity sensor, the compass and the GPS, values that I'm going to use for my robotics project. Yet, I have a problem with the GPS which doesn't update when I change location without closing the Activity. Indeed, if I stop the application and then restart it at another place, the coords will be correct, so that's really a problem of updating. Please notice too that the location is being recalculated when the screen change its orientation (landscape -> portrait). But I would like it to work without touching anything, hehe.

So here is my code :

```
package com.pIndus.sensors;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Sensors extends Activity implements SensorEventListener{

SensorManager sm;
LocationManager lm;
LocationListener ls;
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    sm = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);
    lm = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

    boolean accelSupported = sm.registerListener(this, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    if(!accelSupported)
    {
        sm.unregisterListener(this, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER));
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.acc)).setText("Accéléromètre non disponible");
    }

    boolean compassSupported = sm.registerListener(this, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    if(!compassSupported)
    {
        sm.unregisterListener(this, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION));
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.compass)).setText("Boussole non disponible");
    }

    boolean proxySupported = sm.registerListener(this, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY),SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_FASTEST);

    if(!proxySupported)
    {
        sm.unregisterListener(this, sm.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY));
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.proxy)).setText("Capteur de proximité non disponible");
    }

    ls = new MyLocationListener();


    lm.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ls);

}

@Override
public void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();
    lm.removeUpdates(ls);
    sm.unregisterListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onPause()
{
    super.onStop();
    lm.removeUpdates(ls);
    sm.unregisterListener(this);
}



@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) 
{
    switch(event.sensor.getType())
    {
        case Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER:
            onAccelChanged(event);
        break;

        case Sensor.TYPE_ORIENTATION:
            onCompassChanged(event);
        break;

        case Sensor.TYPE_PROXIMITY:
            onProxyChanged(event);
        break;  
    }

}

public void onAccelChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    float aX,aY,aZ;

    aX = event.values[0];
    aY = event.values[1];
    aZ = event.values[2];

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.axeX)).setText("Axe X : " + aX);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.axeY)).setText("Axe Y : " + aY);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.axeZ)).setText("Axe Z : " + aZ);

}

public void onCompassChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    float azimuth,pitch,roll;

    azimuth = event.values[0];
    pitch = event.values[1];
    roll = event.values[2];

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.azimuth)).setText("Azimuth : " + azimuth);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.pitch)).setText("Pitch : " + pitch);
    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.roll)).setText("Roll : " + roll);
}

public void onProxyChanged(SensorEvent event)
{
    float x;

    x = event.values[0];

    ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.prox)).setText("Proximité : " + x);

}

public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener

{

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double longitude, lattitude;

        longitude = location.getLongitude();
        lattitude = location.getLatitude();

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.longi)).setText("Longitude : " + longitude);
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.latti)).setText("Lattitude : " + lattitude);

         lm.requestLocationUpdates( LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, ls);


    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.warnGPS)).setText("GPS Desactivé");

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        ((TextView)findViewById(R.id.warnGPS)).setText("GPS Activé");

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

}
```

}

Has anyone an idea about my problem ?

Thank you very much for your help and have a nice day/evening/night.

Answer (score 0):

Replace below line by

lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000L, 1.0f, ls);

Comment: Hi, thank you for your contribution. Yet, it doesn't work (it doesn't update).